# UrlDonwloadToFileA UnresolvedExternal Symbol

Tags: c++

I've been trying to use the URLDownloadToFileA function from "urlmon.h" and i keep getting an unresolved extern symbol issue. Here is my code:

```
#include <urlmon.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

URLDownloadToFileA(0, "my_url", "C:\\test.txt",0,0);
```

I also have the urlmon.lib file in my path of my project and i have "urlmon.lib" as the input for the linker and i've also given the linker / compiler the path of the .lib file it self. Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `A`. I don't see that there are wide and narrow versions of that function looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85))

Comment: It still gave me the same error sadly.

Comment: I looked in `urlmon.h` and there are both A and W versions. If I wrap the function call in `int main() { ... }` it compiles and links for me in Visual Studio. Perhaps you can share some more details about the compiler and options you're using?

Comment: @RetiredNinja the documentation shows the function taking `LPCTSTR` (`const TCHAR*`) parameters. That *requires* the function to have wide and narrow versions. And BTW, this is actually stated at the *very bottom* of the documentation: "*Unicode and ANSI names: URLDownloadToFileW (Unicode) and URLDownloadToFileA (ANSI)*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think at this point my brain just translates anything TCHAR related into something less offensive. :)

Comment: Im using the microsoft visual studio compiler the latest version available.